# Obj-C: How to improve repetitive method implementations using method forwarding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, runtime

I have an implementation which contains a set of methods which do pretty much the same:

```
- (NSString *) specialKey{
  [self.mySpecialDictionary valueForKey:@"specialKey"];
}

- (NSString *) anotherKey{
  [self.mySpecialDictionary valueForKey:@"mySpecialKey1"];
}
```

I can now conveniently use those getters like so:

```
NSString *foo = [Setting sharedInstance].specialKey;
```

I guess I should now be able to define my Properties `dynamic` and make **one** implementation for all those cases, since the string which I look up in my dictionary will always be the name of the getter. I am pretty sure that this should be do-able in Objective-C, but I have no Idea how to achieve this.

Comment: you mean you want a sing getter to multiple properties?

Comment: @Besi: Are you sure you want to write your own class for settings rather than use something like NSUserDefaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your question. Try method forwarding:

```
- (NSMethodSignature*) methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    return [mySpecialDictionary methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(valueForKey:)];
}

- (void) forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation
{
    NSString* propertyName = NSStringFromSelector(invocation.selector);
    [invocation setSelector:@selector(valueForKey:)];
    [invocation setArgument:&propertyName atIndex:2];
    [invocation invokeWithTarget:mySpecialDictionary];
}
```

Of course, to get rid of compiler warnings it needs to define every property explicit

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString* specialKey;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString* anotherKey;
```

and provide `@dynamic` for them.

Comment: I used this technique in my TableKit library. [Proxy object](https://github.com/onegray/UITableKit/blob/master/TableKit/Attributes/TKAttrProxy.m) catches all attempts to write to property and saves them in attributes array.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
   - (NSString *)valueForKey:(NSString *)key
   {
        return [self.mySpecialDictionary valueForKey:key];
   }
```

this will return the value for the provided key. Or this for more flexible use

```
- (NSString *)valueForKey:(id)key 
{
    if([key isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
            return [self.mySpecialDictionary valueForKey:key];
    }
}
```

Or even this

```
 - (id)valueForKey:(id)key 
    {
        if([key isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
                return [self.mySpecialDictionary valueForKey:key];
        } else if (..){
               // catch more possible keys here ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to keep my properties though but using a dynamic implementation

Comment: You shouldn't name this `getValueForKey:`. Methods names are conventionally only prefixed with `get` if they return values indirectly. (See [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa: Naming Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF))

Comment: In all your examples, you should replace all instances of
    @"key" with key